# Crontab + Rsync - nothing happens :(

Tags: ssh, rsync, cron

Hello the interesting line in my crontab looks like this:
(edited & saved it by running crontab -e)

```
23 *    * * *   rsync -av --delete root@example.de:/var/www/ /home/niklas >> /home/niklas/scripts/logfile
```

but .. this line does nothing (at the 24th minute no bandwidth is used, no output is in the logfile) can someone tell me what is wrong?

BTW: the authentification for the server works via a passwordless pgp key. that is why the user needs to be 'niklas'

EDIT:

ran `type rsync` which returned `/usr/bin/rsync` but that is already on the path:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

EDIT2:

created /usr/bin/backup containing:

```
rsync -av --delete root@example.com:/var/www/ /home/niklas/server4you_www >> /home/niklas/scripts/logfile
```

chmod +x'ed it and changed the entry in chrontab to

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
16  *   * * *   /usr/bin/backup
```

still... its not working, though /var/log/syslog sais:

```
Aug  1 15:16:01 niklas-desktop CRON[9421]: (niklas) CMD (/usr/bin/backup)
```

please help

EDIT3:

Changing

```
rsync -av --delete root@example.com:/var/www/ /home/niklas/server4you_www >> /home/niklas/scripts/logfile
```

to

```
/usr/bin/rsync -av --delete root@example.com:/var/www/ /home/niklas/server4you_www >> /home/niklas/scripts/logfile
```

as expected does not alter the (unsatisfying) result.
however `putting echo 'xyz' > log writes xyz into the log file

so... as you might guess... my issue is still not resolved.

adding a `|| echo "rsync died with error code $?"` to the backup script returned:

```
rsync died with error code 5
```

which as http://wpkg.org/Rsync_exit_codes suggests means "Error starting client-server protocol" so i guess something is fishy about ssh. again i am using a pgp key with a password but that password is by default unlocked by the keyring on startup so that i can ssh root@example.com without entering a password. Is it possible to send rsync the password of the ssh key?

Comment: You keep mentioning pgp key, but maybe you really mean an SSH keypair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put full path to rsync even to your */usr/bin/backup*, so the line in that file would start

```
/usr/bin/rsync <your other options>
```

And try to put a line like

```
logger -t my_backup Hello from /usr/bin/backup
```

to your /usr/bin/backup script and see if anything gets logged to /var/log/messages (or other log file, depending on your syslog setup). Alternatively you might replace the logger with

```
echo "Hello from /usr/bin/backup" >/tmp/backuptest
```

Oh, sometimes SELinux might cause problems like you have encountered. Is it in use?

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: Make your /usr/bin/backup rsync line be like

```
/usr/bin/rsync <your options> || echo "rsync died with error code $?" >> your_log
```

Perhaps we'll catch why rsync is so upset.

**YET ANOTHER EDIT**: OK, rsync error code 5. That means

```
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol
```

Most of the time that happens due the wrong password, even though the message looks more cryptic.

If you manually run your rsync script as niklas, that works, right?

**EDIT 3**: Spotted your mention about *keyring*. I think cron doesn't use the same keyring than the user niklas during your login. That's why the login goes p00f when trying to run it from cron. Could you use a passwordless RSA key for this instead and just restrict it to run rsync?

**EDIT 4**: Use *RSYNC_PASSWORD* environment variable. That can be done by putting this to top of your backup script:

```
export RSYNC_PASSWORD="myprecioussssssss"
```

or if you would like to store the password in a textfile, create a file and provide a *--password-file* option to rsync.

If that doesn't work, you may provide *-e 'ssh -o IdentityFile=/path/to/your_file* option to rsync.

Comment: I am using ubuntu

Comment: OK, edited my reply a bit :)

Comment: rsync died with error code 5

Comment: Soooooo I edited again.

Comment: in deed running rsync manually works like a charm!

Comment: And yet another edit, spotted your own edit :D

Comment: i'd be much happier if i could tell rsync the password rather than creating a new key.

Comment: OK. How about my latest edit?

Comment: All the methods you mentioned still return error code 5

Answer (score 3):

You included a user name field in your crontab. But that field only exists in the system crontab (`/etc/crontab`), not in the per-user crontab that you edit with `crontab -e`. So edit the crontab with `crontab -e` as user `niklas`, and make the contents

```
23 *    * * *    rsync -av --delete root@example.de:/var/www/ /home/niklas >> /home/niklas/scripts/logfile
```

The user you ran `crontab -e` as should have received a mail with an error message (complaining that `niklas` is not a valid command). If it didn't, there may be a problem in your mail setup.

Answer (score 2):

You might need the full path for the rsync command.

For example, on Fedora 13 you would replace rsync with /usr/bin/rsync

Answer (score 1):

in my case (ubuntu) creating a shellscript and put there rsync command instead of running it from crontab as command did the trick. Now syncing working as charm.